# How can i navigate to another page using picker view

Tags: ios, swift, pickerview

i'm using here switch condition to navigate to another page using picker view and i already mentioned it in my controller but it's just navigate to one of the pages when i press on the second choice in picker view it takes me to the same page of the choice one. 
i create a variable calling optionSelector and i gave him value 0 and i made the switch condition but still working on one page.

```
@IBAction func donePressed(_ sender: Any) {
    mainPV.isHidden = true
    doneBtn.isHidden = true
    optionV.isHidden = true

    switch optionSelector{
    case 0:
        FiltersController.instance.showAreaFilter(nc: self.navigationController!)
    case 1:
        FiltersController.instance.showTrainStations(nc: self.navigationController!)
    case 2:
        FiltersController.instance.showMapFilter(nc: self.navigationController!)
    default:
        FiltersController.instance.showResidintialFilter(nc: self.navigationController!)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might not be updating the value of `optionSelector` on pickerView scroll.

Change `optionSelector` value on `pickerView delegate` method as:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
     // put your logic here.
    self.optionSelector = row
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you might not have the correct value in optionSelector

You can use the selected value of the picker view by:

```
// Assuming you only have 1 component
// By default you only have 1 component
pickerView.selectedRowInComponent(0)
```

So effectively your done method will be:

```
@IBAction func donePressed(_ sender: Any) {
  mainPV.isHidden = true
  doneBtn.isHidden = true
  optionV.isHidden = true

  switch pickerView.selectedRowInComponent(0) {
  case 0:
      FiltersController.instance.showAreaFilter(nc: self.navigationController!)
      break
  case 1:
      FiltersController.instance.showTrainStations(nc: self.navigationController!)
      break
  case 2:
      FiltersController.instance.showMapFilter(nc: self.navigationController!)
      break
  default:
      FiltersController.instance.showResidintialFilter(nc: self.navigationController!)
 }

}
```